# Nullable dates exception handling - is there a better way

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, error-handling

I have this challenge with Nullable dates when trying to handle invalid or empty date input

For normal `DateTime` variable I can do this

```
DateTime d = new DateTime.Now; //You can also use DateTime.MinValue. You cannot assign null here, WHY? 
DateTime.TryParse(ctrlDate.Text, out d);
```

For Nullable DateTime

```
DateTime? nd = null;
DateTime.TryParse(ctrlDate.Text, out nd); //this doesn't work. it expects DateTime not DateTime?
```

> **For DateTime?**
>
> The best overload method match for System.DateTime.TryParse(string,
>   out System.DateTime) has some invalid arguments

So I had to change it to

```
DateTime? nd = null;
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
if(DateTime.TryParse(ctrlDate.Text, out d))
   nd = d;
```

I had to create an extra `DateTime` variable to achieve this for a nullable date.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to create the extra `DateTime` variable, there's no better way.

Though you can of course encapsulate it in your own parsing method:

```
bool MyDateTimeTryParse(string text, out DateTime? result)
{
    result = null;

    // We allow an empty string for null (could also use IsNullOrWhitespace)
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return true;

    DateTime d;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(text, out d)) return false;
    result = d;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to assign anything to the variable that is passed as `out` argument to a method, just:

```
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParse(ctrlDate.Text, out d))
{
    // the date was successfully parsed => use it here
}
else
{
    // tell the user to enter a valid date
}
```

As far as your first question about why you can't write `DateTime d = null;`, well, it's because the DateTime is a value type, not a reference type.

Comment: am concerned about nullable `DateTime?` not `DateTime`. I get _The best overload method match for System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime) has some invalid arguments_

Comment: That's normal. The TryParse method expects a DateTime, not nullable DateTime so you cannot use it with nullable DateTime.

Comment: I think is common practice to initialize local variables?

Comment: No, not if you intend to be passing them to a function that works with `out` argument. It would be absolutely meaningless to assign the variable some value because the whole point of the `out` argument is that the function guarantees you that a value will be assigned **inside** this function and your initial value will be replaced in all cases.

Comment: that makes a better sense than mine

Answer (score 2):

> DateTime d = new DateTime.Now; //You cannot assign null here, WHY?

Because its a **value type**, its a structure, you can't assign null to structures/value types.

For DateTime.TryParse

If you want to use `DateTime.TryParse` then you have to create an extra variable of type `DateTime` and then assign its value to to Nullable DateTime if you want to.

Comment: @codingbiz, you can't use Nullable DateTime, with your DateTime.TryParse method, you may write your own method doing the same thing for Nullable DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
DateTime.MinValue
```

instead of nullable types?

Comment: Why would you need to use that with the `DateTime.TryParse` method?

Comment: @margabit I know about that. I just didn't include it in the question

Comment: He's asking to have nullable DateTime (DateTime?), I think it's easier to manage DateTime without being nullable. If we want to know if it hasn't been set, we can check if value != DateTime.MinValue instead of comparing with Null and casting.